# Grabbing param from request

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to figure out how to grab part of a url from a request. So the user goes to the following url `http://myapp.com?access_token=XXXXXX`, I need to be able to grab the "XXXXXX" and check to see if it is in the database. I am kind of new to rails and don't really know anything about using a `before_filter` in the `ActionController` that I am trying to implement this in. Thanks for any help and guidance in advance.

Comment: There's the `params` object in the controller. You could put a `debugger` statement or a `raise params.inspect` in the controller action or `before_action` to inspect it. `params[:access_token]` should contain the parsed param.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are requesting is really straightforward and is one of the basics of Rails. Even if you are a beginner, you should probably read some book or documentation before jumping straight into coding.

As [explained in this article](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#parameters) request parameters (either POST fields or GET query string fields) are parsed into the `params` hash.

Therefore, in a controller action you can get the value of the `access_token` query string field using

```
params[:access_token]
```

Comment: Thank you I will read this article and try it. I did some digging on google but couldn't find a whole lot.

Answer (score 0):

So to solve this issue I took into consideration what @Simone had mentioned and did the following.
`user = User.where(authentication_token:request.params[:access_token]).take`